# writing to log file causes error 704

Tags: php, apache, fopen, fwrite

Does anyone know what this error means
**FATAL:
Autorisation no longer valid.704**

It happens when I try to write to this file, but the permissions are set to 755 and 0644
The temp folder is in the rootfolder of this subdomain.

```
if ($handle = fopen( 'temp/mylog.log'"a+") )
                {
    if( !fwrite( $handle, $json ) )
    {
    throw new Exception("can't write to ...");
    }
    fclose( $handle );
    }
```

thanks, Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the user who run that script own that folder/file?

do a list

```
# ls -l /rootfolder/temp/
```

to get the user who has privileges to modify the file, I suppose it is **root**

do from your shell the following to allow your user to access the file (change **user** with your username)

```
# chown user /rootfolder/temp/mylog.log
```

also use the full path in fopen.

**UPDATE:**
use this simple steps to write file, if you get errors then it may be something related to permissions

```
$myFile = "/home/woonbel/public_html/tsa.nl/temp/tsa.log";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "Some of your text...bla bla\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: Do you mean with full path, like so--- /home/woonbel/public_html/tsa.nl/temp/tsa.log

Comment: This stuff is for if you own the server, right?? I am on a shared host, but I can mail this to the hoster if it's neccasary?

Comment: I will try something to put the code in a new file, so that i am absolutely sure it's not coming from something else Right now it was setup in an excepction class. I just had my hoster on the phone and he also suggested the path I wrote abobe, but I still get the same error.

Comment: got it, it came from the exception class